# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when trying to use Madrill in Android app

Tags: java, android

I want to send information from Android app and use Madrill service. I tryed to send something on my email by taking the example code from their repository on GitHub. But i get the **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError**:

```
08-04 15:18:09.684    1890-6152/com.kll.app1 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a74ba8)
08-04 15:18:09.694    1890-6152/com.kll.app1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-144
    Process: com.s.a.kll.app1, PID: 1890
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.consume
            at com.microtripit.mandrillapp.lutung.model.MandrillRequestDispatcher.execute(MandrillRequestDispatcher.java:104)
            at com.microtripit.mandrillapp.lutung.controller.MandrillUtil.query(MandrillUtil.java:46)
            at com.microtripit.mandrillapp.lutung.controller.MandrillMessagesApi.send(MandrillMessagesApi.java:94)
            at com.microtripit.mandrillapp.lutung.controller.MandrillMessagesApi.send(MandrillMessagesApi.java:49)
            at com.s.a.kll.app1.Landing$NotificadorEmail.notificar(Landing.java:290)
            at com.s.a.kll.app1.Landing$8$1.run(Landing.java:257)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

It is my code:

```
    public void run(){
                        MandrillApi mandrillApi = new MandrillApi("<put ur Mandrill API key here>");

// create your message
                        MandrillMessage message = new MandrillMessage();
                        message.setSubject("Hello World!");
                        message.setHtml("<h1>Hi pal!</h1><br />Really, I'm just saying hi!");
                        message.setAutoText(true);
                        message.setFromEmail("kitty@yourdomain.com");
                        message.setFromName("Kitty Katz");
// add recipients
                        ArrayList<MandrillMessage.Recipient> recipients = new ArrayList<MandrillMessage.Recipient>();
                        MandrillMessage.Recipient recipient = new MandrillMessage.Recipient();
                        recipient.setEmail("myMail@gmail.com");
                        recipient.setName("Claire Annette");
                        recipients.add(recipient);
                        recipient = new MandrillMessage.Recipient();
                        recipient.setEmail("Ma@gmail.com");
                        recipients.add(recipient);
                        message.setTo(recipients);
                        message.setPreserveRecipients(true);
                        ArrayList<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
                        tags.add("test");
                        tags.add("helloworld");
                        message.setTags(tags);
// ... add more message details if you want to!
// then ... send

                        try {
                            MandrillMessageStatus[] messageStatusReports = mandrillApi.messages().send(message, false);
                        } catch (MandrillApiError mandrillApiError) {
                            mandrillApiError.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

Exeption is in this line:

```
MandrillMessageStatus[] messageStatusReports = mandrillApi.messages().send(message, false);
```

From my searching in the Internet I found, that trouble is in versions of the libraries that I have added, I tried change they, but unsuccessfully. These are my dependencies from **build.grade** file:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile files('build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/22.2.0/jars/libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
compile files('build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/22.2.0/jars/libs/lutung-0.0.5.jar')
compile files('build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/22.2.0/jars/libs/internal_impl-22.2.0.jar')
compile files('build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-v4/22.2.0/jars/libs/httpcore-4.0.1.jar')
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the dependency directly in gradle. This way it will fetch the correct dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.mandrillapp.wrapper.lutung:lutung:0.0.5'
}
```

Make sure there is not any duplicate file in the `libs` directory (httpcore, gson, lutung, etc)

Comment: Thank you for the ansver, but it isnt work(or I do something wrong). If I write dependency as you wrote it gives an error message:

`Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.3 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android. In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages`
 I tried some solutions from the Internet searching, but they did not work.