# Can`t add Mandrill`s JARs whithout conflict in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I want to use in my Android project Madrill`s libraries(I use Gradle). I am tried many times to add secondary libraries(like gson, httpcore..) to the project, but it always conflicted(as far as I understood from searches on the Internet) and I get different errors, mostly like:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

or this:

```
08-04 15:18:09.684    1890-6152/com.kll.app1 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a74ba8)
08-04 15:18:09.694    1890-6152/com.kll.app1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-144
    Process: com.s.a.kll.app1, PID: 1890
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.consume
            at com.microtripit.mandrillapp.lutung.model.MandrillRequestDispatcher.execute(MandrillRequestDispatcher.java:104)
            at com.microtripit.mandrillapp.lutung.controller.MandrillUtil.query(MandrillUtil.java:46)
            at com.microtripit.mandrillapp.lutung.controller.MandrillMessagesApi.send(MandrillMessagesApi.java:94)
            at com.microtripit.mandrillapp.lutung.controller.MandrillMessagesApi.send(MandrillMessagesApi.java:49)
            at com.s.a.kll.app1.Landing$NotificadorEmail.notificar(Landing.java:290)
            at com.s.a.kll.app1.Landing$8$1.run(Landing.java:257)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I used [this guide](http://ethicsoftmagazine.com/34/) and I found the same files, I tried to add JARs a variety of ways, but always I see first error message. (I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817947/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-when-trying-to-use-madrill-in-android-app) a question about it, but perhaps it was necessary to ask it a little differently.)
So, someone could gather these files into one project that they did not create such mistakes?

Comment: You'll need OSGi and modules.

Comment: @duffymo ...for *Android*?

Comment: Only way I know of to have conflicting jars. Please answer with your idea.